How to use RenderTexture correctly
For now, I can just insert , but I want more of an example of how to add my html css component or an image from animation, experts tell me. I use Next js basic js
<meshStandardMaterial>
    <RenderTexture attach="map">
     <PerspectiveCamera manual  position={[0, 0, 6]} />
        <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
        <directionalLight position={[10, 10, 5]} />
        <Text fontSize={2}  color="#555">
            Hello world
        </Text>
    </RenderTexture>
</meshStandardMaterial>

I want to display text or an image that will be coolly animated.
